# How to populate the value of a field on another field on same table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a table that has "customer registration" "Update Billing Address" and "Update Shipping Address" a group of fields. Upon registration the user fills the "customer registration".

I'd like the values on this field ("customer registration") to be populated automatically on "Update Billing Address" and "Update Shipping Address" instead of filling both fields manually. Note these are different fields but on same table in the Database.

How do I achieve this? Please pardon me if this question is too elementary, I've tried to find the answer here from previous post but can't get what I want. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWtgq.png)

[image]

```
<?php require_once('header.php'); ?>

<?php
// Check if the customer is logged in or not
if(!isset($_SESSION['customer'])) {
    header('location: '.BASE_URL.'logout.php');
    exit;
} else {
    // If customer is logged in, but admin make him inactive, then force logout this user.
    $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_customer WHERE cust_id=? AND cust_status=?");
    $statement->execute(array($_SESSION['customer']['cust_id'],0));
    $total = $statement->rowCount();
    if($total) {
        header('location: '.BASE_URL.'logout.php');
        exit;
    }
}
?>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['form1'])) {

    $valid = 1;

    if(empty($_POST['cust_name'])) {
        $valid = 0;
        $error_message .= LANG_VALUE_123."<br>";
    }

    if(empty($_POST['cust_phone'])) {
        $valid = 0;
        $error_message .= LANG_VALUE_124."<br>";
    }

    if(empty($_POST['cust_address'])) {
        $valid = 0;
        $error_message .= LANG_VALUE_125."<br>";
    }

    if(empty($_POST['cust_country'])) {
        $valid = 0;
        $error_message .= LANG_VALUE_126."<br>";
    }

    if(empty($_POST['cust_city'])) {
        $valid = 0;
        $error_message .= LANG_VALUE_127."<br>";
    }

    if(empty($_POST['cust_state'])) {
        $valid = 0;
        $error_message .= LANG_VALUE_128."<br>";
    }

    if(empty($_POST['cust_zip'])) {
        $valid = 0;
        $error_message .= LANG_VALUE_129."<br>";
    }

    if($valid == 1) {

        // update data into the database
        $statement = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE tbl_customer SET cust_name=?, cust_cname=?, cust_phone=?, cust_country=?, cust_address=?, cust_city=?, cust_state=?, cust_zip=? WHERE cust_id=?");
        $statement->execute(array(
                    strip_tags($_POST['cust_name']),
                    strip_tags($_POST['cust_cname']),
                    strip_tags($_POST['cust_phone']),
                    strip_tags($_POST['cust_country']),
                    strip_tags($_POST['cust_address']),
                    strip_tags($_POST['cust_city']),
                    strip_tags($_POST['cust_state']),
                    strip_tags($_POST['cust_zip']),
                    $_SESSION['customer']['cust_id']
                ));  

        $success_message = LANG_VALUE_130;

        $_SESSION['customer']['cust_name'] = $_POST['cust_name'];
        $_SESSION['customer']['cust_cname'] = $_POST['cust_cname'];
        $_SESSION['customer']['cust_phone'] = $_POST['cust_phone'];
        $_SESSION['customer']['cust_country'] = $_POST['cust_country'];
        $_SESSION['customer']['cust_address'] = $_POST['cust_address'];
        $_SESSION['customer']['cust_city'] = $_POST['cust_city'];
        $_SESSION['customer']['cust_state'] = $_POST['cust_state'];
        $_SESSION['customer']['cust_zip'] = $_POST['cust_zip'];
    }
}
?>

<div class="page">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">            
            <div class="col-md-12"> 
                <?php require_once('customer-sidebar.php'); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="user-content">
                    <h3>
                        <?php echo LANG_VALUE_117; ?>
                    </h3>
                    <?php
                    if($error_message != '') {
                        echo "<div class='error' style='padding: 10px;background:#f1f1f1;margin-bottom:20px;'>".$error_message."</div>";
                    }
                    if($success_message != '') {
                        echo "<div class='success' style='padding: 10px;background:#f1f1f1;margin-bottom:20px;'>".$success_message."</div>";
                    }
                    ?>
                    <form action="" method="post">
                        <?php $csrf->echoInputField(); ?>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                                <label for=""><?php echo LANG_VALUE_102; ?> *</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cust_name" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['customer']['cust_name']; ?>">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                                <label for=""><?php echo LANG_VALUE_103; ?></label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cust_cname" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['customer']['cust_cname']; ?>">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                                <label for=""><?php echo LANG_VALUE_94; ?> *</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['customer']['cust_email']; ?>" disabled>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                                <label for=""><?php echo LANG_VALUE_104; ?> *</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cust_phone" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['customer']['cust_phone']; ?>">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                                <label for=""><?php echo LANG_VALUE_105; ?> *</label>
                                <textarea name="cust_address" class="form-control" cols="30" rows="10" style="height:70px;"><?php echo $_SESSION['customer']['cust_address']; ?></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                                <label for=""><?php echo LANG_VALUE_106; ?> *</label>
                                <select name="cust_country" class="form-control">
                                <?php
                                $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_country ORDER BY country_name ASC");
                                $statement->execute();
                                $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                                foreach ($result as $row) {
                                    ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $row['country_id']; ?>" <?php if($row['country_id'] == $_SESSION['customer']['cust_country']) {echo 'selected';} ?>><?php echo $row['country_name']; ?></option>
                                    <?php
                                }
                                ?>
                                </select>                                    
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                                <label for=""><?php echo LANG_VALUE_107; ?> *</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cust_city" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['customer']['cust_city']; ?>">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                                <label for=""><?php echo LANG_VALUE_108; ?> *</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cust_state" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['customer']['cust_state']; ?>">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                                <label for=""><?php echo LANG_VALUE_109; ?> *</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cust_zip" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['customer']['cust_zip']; ?>">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="<?php echo LANG_VALUE_5; ?>" name="form1">
                    </form>
                </div>                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I expect the value of the `cust_name, cust_cname, cust_phone, cust_country, cust_address, cust_city, cust_state, cust_zip` to populate on the equivalent fields. If you understand what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answear is in your code:

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_country ORDER BY country_name ASC");
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($result as $row){ }?>
```

The last foreach is a cicle it runs on all the result table, so if you want to update the filds, you need to change the "question" to the table you want to query and then on the cicle store them in the correct variables cust_name, cust_cname, cust_phone, cust_country, cust_address, cust_city, cust_state, cust_zip i suppose.

Good Luck